# Encode only spaces in jmeter GUI

Tags: http, jmeter

I read a csv file for input in my jmeter test plan. I name the first variable in the row `query`.

[image: Http request]

I need it to encode spaces as `%20` not `+`. Using the `__urlencode()` function like `${__urlencode(${query})}` encodes the spaces as `+` the same way selecting the encode option on the parameter does in the above screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is something you're really want as encoding the URL is not only about spaces.

You should use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function (or its equivalent). The way of calling it in JMeter via [__javaScript](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function will look like:

```
${__javaScript(encodeURIComponent("${query}"),)}
```

If you just need to replace spaces with `%20` you can do it with [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) funciton like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('query').replaceAll(' '\, '%20'),)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Functions]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.