# How to change JMeter's encoding of a space to '%20' instead of '+'

Tags: jmeter, urlencode

In JMeter, I've set up a HTTP Request, doing a `GET` with parameters. The URL Encode flag is set to true (to properly encode the URL). There are spaces in the values of the parameters, so I would expect that the space would be replaced by `%20`. However, they are being replaced by plus (+). Because I'm using ODATA, the spaces should be `%20`. A piece of the value is coming from a test data file `${id}`.

I've tried setting the `Content-Type` to `text/plain` in both the HTTP Header Manager section, as well as the content-type column of the parameters themselves.

This is how the encoding is showing up for one of the parameters:

```
filter=id+eq+%27myuniqueID+%27+and+page+eq+1+and+rpp+eq+300
```

I'm expecting this:

```
filter=id%20eq%20%27myuniqueID%20%27%20and%20page%20eq%201%20and%20rpp%20eq%20300
```

[image: Pic of HTTP Request Setup]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode only spaces in jmeter GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947739/encode-only-spaces-in-jmeter-gui)